# Once Upon a Time Season 7: What is the tower at the start of each episode?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

Season 7 made it to Netflix, and I prefer the more gritty and modern atmosphere.

At the beginning of each episode, a tower is shown.  It's not the tower that Rapunzel was trapped in.  It is a modern tower, presumably in the Hyperion neighbourhood.  What is that tower?  Is it completely fictional, or does it correspond to a tower in the real world?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The Space Needle (Seattle, WA, USA)

The tower in the title card is the [Space Needle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Needle), a prominent landmark in [Seattle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seattle), Washington.  In *Once Upon a Time*, Hyperion Heights is a neighbourhood in Seattle.

The [title card](http://onceuponatime.wikia.com/wiki/File:701Title.png) from *Once Upon a Time*, [Episode 7x01: "Hyperion Heights"](http://onceuponatime.wikia.com/wiki/Hyperion_Heights):

[image: *Once Upon a Time* 7x01 title card]

[Seattle skyline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:20160124_GFJ2741-kerry-park-skyline_seattle-wa-panoramic.jpg) looking southeast from [Kerry Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerry_Park_(Seattle)) toward the Space Needle and [Mount Rainier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Rainier):

[image: Seattle skyline looking southeast from Kerry Park.]

Since the placement of the Space Needle relative to the background buildings is identical in these two images, the title card photograph seems to have been shot from Kerry Park.

Comment: So cool.  Thanks.